# merging two data.tables with duplicates in the column used to merge

Tags: r, merge, duplicates, data.table

I have a question about merging two data.tables. Up to now I couldn´t find any solution here on stackoverflow or anywhere else. Therefore here the question:

The task:
I want to merge two datatables based on a date column (date_dawn). 
As you see, Table A has duplicate dates, as I get the dates from mulitple timestamps throughout a single day (ts.x).
Table B has one date per day (date_dawn) and some columns which I need to attach to Table A.

The error message I get by using merge reads:

```
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
Join results in 1469574 rows; more than 588399 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for 
duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and 
over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the 
large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with 
allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the 
FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.
```

Example Table A

```
 date_dawn         ts.x                  ....
 1: 2015-09-22     2015-09-22 15:15:00
 2: 2015-09-22     2015-09-22 15:20:00
 3: 2015-09-23     2015-09-23 15:25:00
 4: 2015-09-23     2015-09-23 15:30:00
 5: 2015-09-23     2015-09-23 15:35:00
 6: 2015-09-24     2015-09-24 15:40:00
```

Example Table B

```
  date_dawn       ts_ss                 ....
  1: 2015-09-22   2015-09-22 16:58:26
  2: 2015-09-23   2015-09-23 16:56:09
  3: 2015-09-24   2015-09-24 16:53:51
  4: 2015-09-25   2015-09-25 16:51:33
  5: 2015-09-26   2015-09-26 16:49:16
  6: 2015-09-27   2015-09-27 16:46:59
```

The desired output would be:

```
   date_dawn         ts.x                  ts_ss                 ....
   1: 2015-09-22     2015-09-22 15:15:00    2015-09-22 16:58:26
   2: 2015-09-22     2015-09-22 15:20:00    2015-09-22 16:58:26
   3: 2015-09-23     2015-09-23 15:25:00    2015-09-23 16:56:09
   4: 2015-09-23     2015-09-23 15:30:00    2015-09-23 16:56:09
   5: 2015-09-23     2015-09-23 15:35:00    2015-09-23 16:56:09
   6: 2015-09-24     2015-09-24 15:40:00    2015-09-24 16:53:51
```

The problem so far was that any other "solution" (like in the function left_join, or in using allow.cartesian = T in the merge function as supposed by the error message above) used all kinds of combinations of the matches between x and y. But I want only the rows of Table B with a certain date_dawn written to the rows in Table A with the according date_dawn.

Thanks for any suggestions

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was that I got duplicates in both tables. Therefore I had to either merge based upon multiple columns, or to make sure there were no duplicates in one of the tables. This way it was possible to merge without getting all possible combinations between the duplicates in Table A and B. 
Sorry if I caused confusion, and thanks to the community for the support.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your desired output!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the issue, you can easily join the two, i.e.: with `dplyr` below

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    x = rep(c("x", "y"), 5),
    a = sample(1:5, 10, replace = T)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
    x = c("x", "y"),
    b = LETTERS[1:2]
)

library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = "x")
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you could just use `inner_join`, you can read the doc of all `?dplyr::join`.

```
library(dplyr)

# with duplicates
df1 <- data.frame(
  date_dawn = sample(
    seq.Date(Sys.Date() - 2, Sys.Date(), by  = "day"), 
    10, 
    replace = TRUE
  ),
  ts.x = seq.Date(Sys.Date() - 9, Sys.Date(), by  = "day")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  date_dawn = seq.Date(Sys.Date() - 2, Sys.Date(), by  = "day"),
  ts_ss = seq.Date(Sys.Date() - 100, Sys.Date() - 98, by = "day")
)

# merge
inner_join(df1, df2, by = "date_dawn")
```

Comment: @ John Coene: I edited the question, and the problem is that left_join uses all possible combinations.

Comment: @ John Coene: I still get the problem, that I get a result table with 2.506274 times the length it should have (namely the lenght of Table A). I think that the problem is that also inner_join uses all combinations.

Comment: @RasK It's difficult to understand what you want, particularly without a reproducible example. What do you mean by "all combinations"?